# Nginx c++ dynamic module fails to load

Tags: c++, nginx, dynamic

I have a C++ module developed for apache HTTP which now Im trying to port to Nginx. For this I started reading about creating dynamic modules and specifically c++. I already found ngx_cpp_test_module.cpp in the source and able to compile it. I extended it a little and wrote a hello world program which compiles fine but when I restart Nginx I get following error:

```
[build@8e269df38d20 nginx-1.16.1]$ sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_cpp_hello_module.so" failed (/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_cpp_hello_module.so: undefined symbol: ngx_http_cpp_hello_module) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
```

I have configured it as follows:

```
./configure --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-lstdc++ -lrt -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fPIC' --prefix=/home/build --add-dynamic-module=/mnt/src/hello-world-cpp --with-threads
```

The config:

```
ngx_addon_name=ngx_http_cpp_hello_module

if test -n "$ngx_module_link"; then
ngx_module_type=HTTP
ngx_module_name=$ngx_addon_name
ngx_module_srcs="$ngx_addon_dir/ngx_http_cpp_hello_world_module.cpp"

. auto/module
else
HTTP_MODULES="$HTTP_MODULES ngx_http_hello_module"
NGX_ADDON_SRCS="$NGX_ADDON_SRCS $ngx_addon_dir/ngx_http_cpp_hello_world_module.cpp"
fi
```

As per the error "undefined symbol: ngx_http_cpp_hello_module" Im trying to understand why it is trying to find that function in the code.
Is there something that I'm missing during configuring or compilation process?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I donot have any function named `ngx_http_cpp_hello_module` . Now Im wondering where should that be? I dont have `ngx_cpp_test_module`. Here is code: https://pastebin.com/ujvxXHE4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the `ngx_module_name` documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/new_config/#key-ngx_module_name):

> The names used in this should be the same names as the **module definition struct**

<sub>[Emphasis **not** mine]</sub>

You have

```
ngx_module_name=$ngx_addon_name
```

which will be expanded to

```
ngx_module_name=ngx_http_cpp_hello_module
```

That means nginx will look for a module definition structure by the name `ngx_http_cpp_hello_module` in your module. If you don't provide such a structure you will get an error such as yours.

A quick look at the [HTTP access module](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_access_module.c) will show you an example of that modules "module structure":

```
ngx_module_t  ngx_http_access_module = { ... };
```

You need to create such a structure yourself, and initialize it.

Also see [the documentation for `ngx_module_t`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/extending/api/main/#ngx-module-t).